# Gradle thinks `compile` dependency as `apk` dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a compiled library `aar` published to and hosted on a local maven.

```
compile("com.a.b:library:0.0.1@aar"){
    changing = true
    transitive = true
}
```

However gradle throws an error:

```
Project :app: apk-only dependencies can only be jars. library@aar is an Android Library.
```

This is with Android Gradle Plugin version 2.3.3 and Gradle version `4.1-rc-1`

The library project has the same configuration.